# Python argparse option subparsers

Tags: python, argparse

I have been trying to come up with a way to get argparse working with nested optional subparsers.

A basic example of what I would like to see is having a 'first' subparser, search, which performs a search on some data I have. This has a few optional things we can search on (for example, all, group, type, tags, etc). An example might look like

```
$ python test.py search --type <type> --group <group>
```

Then I would like to have *optional* subparsers that interact with those search results, for example updating or deleting entries. An example would look like:

```
$ python test.py search --type <type> --group <group> update --tags <new_tags>
```

The problem I am running into is that when I put the 'update' parser as a subparser for the 'search' subparser, if I run the first example I get the error:

```
$ python test.py search --type <type> --group <group>
test.py search: error: too few arguments
```

To get around this I've heard nargs suggested (http://www.alanbriolat.co.uk/optional-positional-arguments-with-argparse.html) but I couldn't get it working with the --option  stuff. Perhaps I am missing something there? I was also looking at bug 9253 (http://bugs.python.org/issue9253), specifically the 'git remote' part, but I didn't see a solution in there.

Any advice for getting this working in argparse? I could roll my own arguement parser for this if needed, but it would be better if I could utilize argparse.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need to define just the first parser, parse the argv (search opts [N]) and then take the remaining argv ([N]) and pass it to another parser instance.

Answer (score 1):

If I read you correctly this really isn't about nested subparsers, but about making subparsers optional.

A subparser argument is a positional argument that takes choices.  It is, effectively, required.  Optionals take a a 'required' parameter, but positionals do not.

But as discussed in Bug 9253, in the development version, subparsers have become optional (not required).  That's because there was a change in how argparse tested for missing arguments.  I proposed a patch that makes subparsers required by default, but also gave the user the option of making it not-required.  http://bugs.python.org/file29793/required.patch

Unfortunately this involves tweaking the argparse internals.

How about leaving out the nested subparsers, and using `parse_known_args`?  If my guess is correct the optional nested subparser command (and its arguments) will be returned in the 'rest', which you could then handle with a new parser.